# Java: Crop out an area with specific color from an image

Tags: java, image

I was wondering if there is a way to crop out an area of an image with a specified color?

I have an image which is a canvas area with an actual image on it and I want to remove the "canvas" area and be left only with the actual image.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224808), if your image has a "distinct background color, use a [`LookupOp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/LookupOp.html) with a four-component LookupTable that sets the alpha component to zero for colors that match the background."

Addendum: See also [*Using the Java 2D LookupOp Filter Class to Process Images*](https://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3654171/Using-the-Java-2D-LookupOp-Filter-Class-to-Process-Images.htm) and [*Image processing with Java 2D*](https://web.archive.org/web/20100126030254/http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-1998/jw-09-media.html).

Comment: Sorry to be a pest about it but is it possible to send an example about using LookupTable and LookupOp in this manner?

Tried to do it but I guess I'm not doing something right.