# Drawing blured shadow in JfreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart, blur, shadow

That's is question is in the title of this post, but anyway:

I use the JFreeChart to create chart in my app. And one of requirement is a soft blured shadow instead solid, which is presented by default.

I know I can add my image instead the default shadow, using

```
setShadowPaint(Paint paint);
```

but this way implies the creating blured image and adding it to the my report. Is there built case to achive needed effect ?

Thanks for all.

Comment: would you please rephrase this line `but this way implies the creating blured image and adding it to the my report. Is there built case to achive needed effect ?` its not clear

Comment: I keep in mind that I can prepare blured image via the code and use this image in setShadowPaint. I'm looking for built-in method for this.

Comment: There's nothing built-in, but you can use a `ConvolveOp` to blur an image. See the articles cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3528196/230513).

Comment: You are welcome; I've elaborated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, but you can use a `ConvolveOp` to blur an image; see the articles cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528196/230513) for examples. You should be able to compose a suitable image in a `BufferedImage` and add it to the chart as an [annotation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/package-summary.html).

Comment: What do you mean "annotaion"?

Comment: Follow the link; I was thinking an image annotation, but you may want to look at the others.

Comment: Mmm. it looks looks usefully. but ny chart is Pie, and annotation is only XYChart's feature.Bad.

Comment: `ImageTitle` might be an alternative.

Comment: Can give you the hint about this my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405062/gradient-fill-under-the-line-xyplot-chart-in-jfreechart    ?