# How to take raster scan of order 2 x 3 in java?

Tags: java, image, raster

I have an buffered image(Say *Ib*). 
I want to take raster scan to order 2 x 3 block(Say *Bb*) with pixels *p1,p2...p6*.
How to do this in java?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [`ConvolveOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ConvolveOp.html); see the articles cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528196/230513) for examples.