# Java Code Color Function Error

Tags: java, swing, paint

Aloha,

i have trouble finding the error in my java code. In my opinion everything is fine and correct but the function is not executed correctly and I dont understand why. The function should detect the difference between the colors and calculate the arithmetic mean of them.
The resilt of it should be draw under the original picture. What did I miss, please help me?

```
package edge;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.image.MemoryImageSource;
import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
*
* @author Alaska
*/
public class Edge extends JComponent {

final int W = 500;
final int H = 300;
Image m_TrgImg, m_SrcImg;

public Edge(JFrame father) {
    try {
        FileDialog diag = new FileDialog(father);
        diag.setVisible(true);
        m_SrcImg = getToolkit().getImage(diag.getDirectory() + diag.getFile()).getScaledInstance(W, H, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
        mt.addImage(m_SrcImg, 0);
        mt.waitForAll();

        int[] srcPix = new int[W * H];
        int[] trgPix = new int[W * H];

        PixelGrabber grab = new PixelGrabber(m_SrcImg, 0, 0, W, H, srcPix, 0, W);
        grab.getPixels();

        MemoryImageSource imgProd = new MemoryImageSource(W, H, trgPix, 0, W);
        m_TrgImg = createImage(imgProd);
        detectEdges(srcPix, trgPix);
        m_TrgImg.flush();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(m_SrcImg, 0, 0, this);
    g.drawImage(m_TrgImg, 0, H, this);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return getMinimumSize();
}

@Override
public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
    return new Dimension(W, H * 2);
}

private void detectEdges(int[] srcPix, int[] trgPix) {
    for (int x = 0; x < W; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < H; ++y) {
            trgPix[y * W + x] = compColor(srcPix, x, y);
        }
    }
}

private int getRed(int col) {
    return (col >> 16) & 255;
}

private int getGreen(int col) {
    return (col >> 8) & 255;
}

private int getBlue(int col) {
    return col & 255;
}

private int compColor(int[] srcPix, int x, int y) {
    int red = 0;
    int green = 0;
    int blue = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    final int IDX = y * W + x;
    final int RED = getRed(srcPix[IDX]);
    final int GREEN = getGreen(srcPix[IDX]);
    final int BLUE = getBlue(srcPix[IDX]);
    for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; ++dx) {
        for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; ++dy) {
            if (dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
                final int X = x + dx;
                final int Y = y + dy;
                final int LOCAL_IDX = Y * W + X;
                if (0 <= X && X < W && 0 <= Y && Y < H) {
                    ++cnt;
                    red   +=  Math.abs(RED -   getRed(srcPix[LOCAL_IDX]));
                    green +=  Math.abs(GREEN - getGreen(srcPix[LOCAL_IDX]));
                    blue  +=  Math.abs(BLUE -  getBlue(srcPix[LOCAL_IDX]));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0xff000000 | (255 - (red / cnt) << 16) | (255 - (green / cnt) << 8) | (255 - (blue / cnt));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new Edge(f));

    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

} 
}
```

Comment: call `super.paintComponent(g)`

Comment: where exactly, please?

Comment: `paintComponent(Graphics g){ super.paintComponent(g) .. //your code }`

Comment: still nothing to see.

Comment: Why not `ConvolveOp`, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14412962/230513)? See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab.grabPixels(), not grab.getPixels().

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html

Also what trashgod said about Initial Threads. You need to create your GUI with SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

*Edit*

The method is executed correctly but you are getting all black values on the input because your pixel array contains only the initialized values which is 0.

Comment: Thanks that was correct. I thought i wrote grabPixels...good to know. thx