# Making black & white buffered images colored in java

Tags: java, colors, bufferedimage

I'v been making a game in java from scratch and have recently come to an issue when trying to color black and white BuffereImages. I want to keep the darkness of the pixels (if that makes any sense). For example, the grass in Minecraft is a gray image, but when seen in game it comes in different shades of green, but keeps its value. I don't have any code to show because I don't know where to start. All I have is a couple BufferedImages that I want to color. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the black and white as an alpha mask (whiter means ligher green, black means darker green or vice-versa).   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221830/set-bufferedimage-alpha-mask-in-java for one approach

Comment: so use a solid color and display a half transparent version of the image on top of it?

Comment: Yes, that's it in a nutshell.

Comment: That worked great! but I used my graphics object to display a green sheet over it, this may seem stupid, but how would I set 1 tile to the color and save the image?

Comment: Update your BufferedImage using the mask, then use ImageIO to write it to disk.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html for ways to write a BufferedImage to specific file formas.

Comment: I'm not interested in saving it, I want code to set it to a color without having to render it.

Comment: The code in the first link I posted updates pixels in a BufferedImage without rendering it.

Comment: I already set up a tile object (I'm working on tile-map rendering atm) with its image and a mask. when it renders the images it will lay a mask on top. Works great and using the animation capabilities I added to the tile object, I was able to get grass to flash different colors :P

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Color.getHSBColor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getHSBColor%28float,%20float,%20float%29) to find a gamut of saturations or values for a given hue, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124507/230513) for saturation. Use a suitable `LookupOp` to update the the image, as shown in the articles cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528196/230513).