# Find the dimensions of the smallest viewable rectangle of an image

Tags: java, image

Using Java imaging how would I find the smallest viewable rectangle of an image. Here I would consider alpha/transparent pixels to be non-viewable. I would like to find the dimensions so that I can perform an auto crop of the image. I would like to do this in an image neutral way, but if this is not possible then PNG.

Comment: *"smallest viewable rectangle of an image"* What about animated GIFs?  The viewable are might change from frame to frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crop image to smallest size by removing transparent pixels in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224561/crop-image-to-smallest-size-by-removing-transparent-pixels-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you don't want to crop out even a single "viewable" pixel, I would use the following algorithm:

Scan the topmost horizontal line, iterating pixel by pixel. If no viewable pixels exist in that line, advance to the second topmost line and so on until you find a line with a viewable pixel.

Do the same for the bottom, advancing upwards, and also for the sides, advancing inwards.

After all 4 steps, you will have how many lines of pixels you can trim from each side of the image.

Comment: Yes this is what I would do, just wondering how can I tell in a format neutral way whether the pixel is transparent or not.

Comment: Look at the methods for `BufferedImage` related to pixels to find it returns a `Color`, or an 'int' representing a color.  Look at the methods for `Color` to see they have constructors that accept an 'int', as well as methods that tell transparency.  Or a less subtle way of putting that is RTFM.