# Remove transparent bound from Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm working on a method to remove the transparent bounds of a Bitmap. The method looks like this:

```
private static final int STEP = 4;//Don't check all the pixel, only a sampling

private Bitmap clipTransparent(Bitmap image) {
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    final int width = image.getWidth();
    final int height = image.getHeight();
    for (x1 = 0; x1 < width - 1; x1 += STEP) {
        if (checkColumn(image, x1)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    x1 = Math.max(0, x1 - STEP);
    for (x2 = width - 1; x2 > x1; x2 -= STEP) {
        if (checkColumn(image, x2)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    x2 = Math.min(width, x2 + STEP);

    for (y1 = 0; y1 < height - 1; y1 += STEP) {
        if (checkRow(x1, x2, image, y1)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    y1 = Math.max(0, y1 - STEP);

    for (y2 = height - 1; y2 > 0; y2 -= STEP) {
        if (checkRow(x1, x2, image, y2)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    y2 = Math.min(height, y2 + STEP);
    try {
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}

private boolean checkColumn(Bitmap image, int x1) {
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y += STEP) {
        if (Color.alpha(image.getPixel(x1, y)) > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean checkRow(int x1, int x2, Bitmap image, int y1) {
    for (int x = x1; x < x2; x += STEP) {
        if (Color.alpha(image.getPixel(x, y1)) > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works great, but not as fast as I would like it to be.
The bottleneck of the code is to get the color of a pixel.

Now I read that value by calling `image.getPixel(x, y)`, but looking at the source code of Android, `getPixel` checks the indexes and does other stuff that slows the code down (`x>=0 && x<getWidth() && y>=0 && y<getHeight() && !isRecycled`)...

Is there a way to access the pixel data without any index check or other useless stuff (useless in my case of course)?

PS: I already tryed to use getPixels() that returns a int array containing all the colors. But the image is big and allocating all the memory triggers a GC... the result was an even slower method

Comment: Please look this solution, sounds great.
[This guy remove the bounds of the transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224561/crop-image-to-smallest-size-by-removing-transparent-pixels-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) you can pass an array to `getPixels()` which you can later reuse. This way no GC should ever happen.

Comment: The problem is taht i need to do the operation only once, and the Bitmap is big (1920x1080). I have no way to reuse a 2MB array

Comment: Use a smaller array and call the method a couple of times.